# using euler's theorem (phi/totient function) to compute order of group elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, totient-function

The question is to prove that every element of $(Z / 72Z)^{\times}$ has order dividing $12$, somehow using Euler's theorem to first reach the fact that every element has order dividing $24$, and then proceeding from there. I am very confused; I can't see how Euler's theorem/phi function are to be used here.

Comment: since $\phi(72)=24$ you know that $a^{24}=1$ for all the elements of $(Z/72Z)^{\times}$. Then you can use the fact that the least number satisfying $a^k=1$ is the order of $a$ to conclude that the order divides $24$. From here you just need to rule out the $24$ case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* By the Chinese remainder theorem,
$$
(\mathbb Z / 72\mathbb Z)^{\times}
\cong
(\mathbb Z / 8)^{\times}
\times
(\mathbb Z / 9)^{\times}
\cong
C_4 \times C_6
$$
and $lcm(4,6)=12$.

Comment: solutions like these really reinforce how beautiful math is to me. thank you very much!